# Android: How to fire CallDetailActivity intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, calllog

I am super new to android, how to fire CallDetailActivity intent?

From LogCat:

Intent {dat=content://call_log/calls/48 cmp=com.android.contacts/.CallDetailActivity}

48 is the id, from CallLog.

How do I construct the intent to fire the event like above? given id

Regards,

Johnny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` with the `Uri` to the call. If all you have is just the ID, try using `ContentUris` and `withAppendedId()` to add your ID to `CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI`.

Answer (score 0):

based on the solution provided by CommonsWare
here is the code :
it would retrieve the latest entry to the log and open the Call Detail Activity

```
Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, "DATE DESC");
        int id=0;
        if (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            id = managedCursor.getInt(managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID));
        }
        managedCursor.close();
        Intent showCallLog = new Intent();
        showCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, id);
        showCallLog.setData(uri);
        startActivity(showCallLog);
```